# Serialization in embedded - using cereal without RTTI?

Tags: c++, serialization, stm32f4, cereal

I want to use Cereal 1.2.1 in an embedded system, so I can't use RTTI as it's adding lots of code size. I have to drop support for typeid.
Is there a way to use Cereal without RTTI? The structures I'm serializing are not polymorphic, just containers of some numbers and arrays of numbers.

I'm using gcc 5.4.1 if it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: cereal mostly uses rtti for polymorphic support. If you disable rtti most of the errors you see will be due to calls to `typeid` related to polymorphism support or support for `virtual_base_class`. With some effort you could remove these parts of the code without affecting the core serialization. Perhaps you may want to open an issue on github for this as a feature request, we could potentially conditionally exclude code, but this would likely be a fairly low priority for development.

Comment: I've resorted to msgpack for now, but adding this feature to cereal would be a great help for further development.
I'll open an issue for this feature request